# g:set blocks out my code

Tags: grails

I am making a Grails application for a school project and I have run across a problem.

When using `<g:set>` 
nothing appears at all on the web page my gsp generates.

Here is my full profile.gsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Personably</title>
</head>
<g:set value="${person}" var="person" scope="page">
    <body>
        <div class="profile">
            ${person.name} <br/>
            ${person.school}, ${person.major}   
        </div>      
    </body>
</g:set>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [documentation of Set tag](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/set.html). In your use case the tag does not take a body, but instead is self-closing, i.e.:

```
<g:set value="${person}" var="person" scope="page" />
<body>
    <div class="profile">
        ${person.name} <br/>
        ${person.school}, ${person.major}   
    </div>      
</body>
```

Comment: now i get Caused by MissingPropertyException: No such property: name for class: java.lang.String cause by ${person.name}. I have used an identical implementation to access the name property of my person class in a template gsp where I passed the var, "person", from a collection using <g:render>.

Comment: how are you passing the ${person} in this page?

Comment: If you pass a body to the _set_ tag, the contents of the body are assigned to _var_. They are not rendered to the page. You need to look into how you pass the original _${person}_ model to the page.